# copy object with collection of frameworkElements -> only shows the copied elements

Tags: c#, wpf, frameworkelement

I have a "board" where I'm showing framework elements. The Problem is, if I clone the "BlockContainer" object and make a new instance of my frameworkElements (System.Windows.Controls.Image), then I see multiple objects.

But if I just make a new instance of "BlockContainer" and then set the list with FrameworkElements from the ReferenceList to the new object, only the new Items are shown.

But i need to have a reference. If the Images changes, I just want to update the referenceList.

(all code is trimmed)

#### base class

```
public abstract class HtMultipleDragSelectionBoardCoordinates : FrameworkContentElement, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    // ##############################################################################################################################
    // Properties
    // ##############################################################################################################################

    /// <summary>
    /// The x - coordinate of the location of the Item.
    /// </summary>
    public double X
    {
        get { return _X; }
        set
        {
            _X = Math.Round(value, 1);
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("X"));
        }
    }
    private double _X;

    /// <summary>
    /// The y - coordinate of the location of the Item.
    /// </summary>
    public double Y
    {
        get { return _Y; }
        set
        {
            _Y = Math.Round(value, 1);
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Y"));
        }
    }
    private double _Y;

    /// <summary>
    /// The rotation of the Item.
    /// </summary>
    public double Rotation
    {
        get { return _Rotation; }
        set
        {
            if (value > 360.0)
                value -= 360.0;
            else if (value < 0.0)
                value += 360.0;

            _Rotation = Math.Round(value, 1);
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Rotation"));
        }
    }
    private double _Rotation;

    // ##############################################################################################################################
    // EventHandler
    // ##############################################################################################################################

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="PropertyChanged"/> EventHandler.
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Raise a the Event.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="propertyName"></param>
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

#### BoardItem

```
public class HtMultipleDragSelectionBoardItem : HtMultipleDragSelectionBoardCoordinates
{
    // ##############################################################################################################################
    // Konstruktor
    // ##############################################################################################################################

    /// <summary>
    /// This ViewModel is required to build items for the <see cref="HTMultipleDragSelectionBoard"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xCoordinate">The x - coordinate of the location of the ViewModel.</param>
    /// <param name="yCoordinate">The y - coordinate of the location of the ViewModel.</param>
    /// <param name="rotation">The rotation of the ViewModel.</param>
    /// <param name="frameworkElement">The <see cref="FrameworkElement"/> to be displayed.</param>
    public HtMultipleDragSelectionBoardItem(double xCoordinate, double yCoordinate, double rotation, FrameworkElement frameworkElement)
    {
        this.X = xCoordinate;
        this.Y = yCoordinate;
        this.Rotation = rotation;
        this.FrameworkElement = frameworkElement;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This ViewModel is required to build items for the <see cref="HTMultipleDragSelectionBoard"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public HtMultipleDragSelectionBoardItem()
    {
    }

    // ##############################################################################################################################
    // Properties
    // ##############################################################################################################################

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="FrameworkElement"/> to be displayed.
    /// </summary>
    public FrameworkElement FrameworkElement
    {
        get { return _FrameworkElement; }
        set
        {
            if (Equals(_FrameworkElement, value)) return;
            _FrameworkElement = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FrameworkElement");
        }
    }
    private FrameworkElement _FrameworkElement;
}
```

#### Container

```
public class HtMultipleDragSelectionBoardItemContainer : HtMultipleDragSelectionBoardCoordinates
{

    // ##############################################################################################################################
    // Properties
    // ##############################################################################################################################

    /// <summary>
    /// The Collection with all <see cref="HtMultipleDragSelectionBoardItem"/>s.
    /// </summary>
    public ObservableCollection<HtMultipleDragSelectionBoardItem> Items
    {
        get { return _Items; }
        set
        {
            if (_Items == value) return;
            _Items = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Items");

            if(_Items != null)
                Items.CollectionChanged -= ItemsOnCollectionChanged;

            Items.CollectionChanged += ItemsOnCollectionChanged;
        }
    }

    private void ItemsOnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs notifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)
    {
        OnPropertyChanged("MinX");
        OnPropertyChanged("MaxX");
        OnPropertyChanged("MinY");
        OnPropertyChanged("MaxY");
        OnPropertyChanged("BorderWidth");
        OnPropertyChanged("BorderHeight");
        OnPropertyChanged("Width");
        OnPropertyChanged("Height");
    }

    private ObservableCollection<HtMultipleDragSelectionBoardItem> _Items;

}
```

#### BlockContainer (is bound to the Visu)

```
public class BlockContainer : HtMultipleDragSelectionBoardItemContainer
{       
    /// <summary>
    /// This is the Reference Block!
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsReferenceBlock
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsReferenceBlockProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsReferenceBlockProperty, value); }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is the Reference Block!
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsReferenceBlockProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsReferenceBlock", typeof(bool), typeof(BlockContainer), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public BlockContainer Clone()
    {
        BlockContainer clone = new BlockContainer
        {
            X = this.X,
            Y = this.Y,
            Rotation = this.Rotation,
            IsReferenceBlock = this.IsReferenceBlock
        };


        foreach (HtMultipleDragSelectionBoardItem item in Items)
        {
            Image image = item.FrameworkElement as Image;
            if (image != null)
            {
                Image newImage = new Image
                {
                    Source = image.Source,
                    Width = item.FrameworkElement.Width,
                    Height = item.FrameworkElement.Height
                };

                FrameworkElement frameworkElement = newImage;
                frameworkElement.Width = newImage.Width;
                frameworkElement.Height = newImage.Height;

                HtMultipleDragSelectionBoardItem newItem = item.Clone();
                newItem.FrameworkElement = frameworkElement;

                clone.Items.Add(newItem);
            }
        }


        return clone;
    }
}
```

#### ReferenceBlock

```
/// <summary>
/// The internal reference Block
/// </summary>
private readonly BlockContainer _ReferenceBlock = new BlockContainer();
```

#### Clone Block (We see all objects)

```
BlockContainer clone = (BlockContainer)((BlockContainer)ListBox_Blocks.SelectedItem).Clone();
```

[image: clone]

#### New Instance with Reference (we only see the new objects)

```
BlockContainer clone = new BlockContainer();
clone.Items = _ReferenceBlock.Items;
```

[image: copy1]
[image: copy2]

Comment: UI elements can only have one parent. This means you can't show the same Image control multiple times.

Comment: Thank you @Clemens.